# Make regex safari compatible by removing negative lookbehind

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

As far as I have read, negative lookbehind doesn't work in safari, so I am trying to modify my regex to make it safari compatible.

This is the regex:

```
(?<!\[(?=#\w+]))#\w+|(?<!\[(?=@\S+\s+\S+]))@(\S+\s+\S+)
```

For the first group before the OR operator, which is `(?<!\[(?=#\w+]))#\w+`, I tried the following: `((?!\[)(?=#\w+]))#\w+`.

I want to match any hashtag word (# followed by any word, such as #something), but only if the group isn't surrounded by square brackets (e.g. [#something]). The latter expression from above doesn't work as it matches words that are surrounded by square brackets as well.

Also, I'm not quite sure if negative lookbehind is the only thing not working in safari, so a heads up would be appreciated. I'm horrible at regex, so help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Based on the fourth bird answer, I managed to derive the result for the second part as well, the entire regex looks like this:

```
\[#[^\]\[]*]|(#\w+)|(\[@[^\]\[]\S+\s+\S+]|(@\S+\s+\S+))
```

And the proper groups can be captured with this:

```
Array.from(str.matchAll(regex), m => m[1] || m[3]).filter(Boolean)
```

Comment: What are you trying to match with `(?<!\[(?=@\S+\s+\S+]))@(\S+\s+\S+)`? Can you add few valid and invalid matches?

Comment: @anubhava Yeah, sorry for not specifying that, I'm trying to match a pattern that looks like this: \@word1 word2, but which isn't surrounded by square brackets ([\@word1 word2] would fail). (without the backslash)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could rule out matching a hashtag between square brackets by matching it, and use an alternation and a capture group to capture what you want.

For example:

```
\[#[^\]\[]*]|(#\w+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4VqN6g/1)

```js
const regex = /\[#[^\]\[]*]|(#\w+)/g;
const str = `[#something]
#something`;
console.log(Array.from(str.matchAll(regex), m => m[1]).filter(Boolean));
```